# PVDF sensor response time

Tags: sensor

I am trying to measure the voltage response from a high energy impact using the PVDF sensors. Here is a description of the experiment. I would like to measure the high impact energy on the aluminised kapton foil, which is attached to a frame and the sensors are placed diagonally at the corners of the foil. These sensors are attached to the oscilloscope and the response can be seen through the picosope software. The problem is that I am getting unexpected response from these sensors like getting a negative peak first in only 2 of the sensors closest to impact and then a positive peak. The responses are also spread farther apart in time and the expected time difference between these different signals do not match the calculated ones.

I have tried repeated the measurements several times and I get the same kind of unexpected results. If someone has an experience using PVDF sensors, some inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Comment: PVDF is polyvinylidene difluoride